# Hiding Cardview until search is initiated

Tags: android, hidden, searchview, invisible, cardview

I've followed the code on http://www.camposha.info/source/android-recyclerview-search-filter and made my search filter work. The only thing I need is when opening the activity to keep the Cardview hidden, or invisible until the search has started in the searchbar (in other words, to keep the Cardview hidden until I start typing something in the searchbar).
I have read the comments which I should have edited the Edittext but I don't have it. what should I do?

Comment: you should not set adapter in onCreate() method of Activity. and set Adaper while you set search in the searchbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the cardview's visibility gone in the layout. And add a queryTextListener to your searchView

```
yourSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if(newText.length()>0){
        yourCardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
        yourCardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error of " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.CardView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference"
  CardView cv;
  cv = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.mcardView);
 sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
  Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
 return true;
     }
  Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
if(newText.length()>0){
cv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }else{
cv.setVisibility(View.GONE)               
return true;
      }